# ¿Cómo ejecutar un método al dar clic a una push notification de Cloud Messaging de Firebase en FLUTTER?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-messaging

Estoy usando firebase messaging y lo que quiero lograr es que al dar click a la notificación push me muestre x mensaje para después ejecutar algo, tengo entendido que es con el onMessageOpenedApp, pero por alguna razón no lo ejecuta ni me muestra nada. Las notificaciones sí las muestra sin problemas, para mandar la notificación tengo una función en node js. Revisé y en la AuthorizationStatus sí está autorizado, así que no sé que pasa. Sí me ayudan se los agradecería mucho.
Intenté probando primero con la app abierta, despues background y al final cerrada, pero nada funciona.

```
 @override
  initState() {
   
    checkStatusNotification();

    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> checkStatusNotification() async {
    FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );
    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      loadFCM();
      listenFCM();
    }
  }

  void loadFCM() async {
    if (!kIsWeb) {
      channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
        //default importance notification channel
        'high_importance_channel',
        'High Importance Notifications',
        importance: Importance.defaultImportance,
        enableVibration: true,
        enableLights: false,
      );

      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
      await FirebaseMessaging.instance
          .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      );
    }
  }

  void listenFCM() async {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      //mostrar mensaje al presionar la push notification
      log("ejecutando onMessageOpenedApp");
    });
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      log('foreground');
     //muestro la notificacion receivedMessages(message);
    });
  }
```

Node js, aqui agregue varias veces el click action para ver si funcionaba pero no

```
function sendNotificationFMC(tokens, title, body, notification) {
  for (const token of tokens) {
    var payload = {
      notification: {
        title: title,
        body: body,
        channel_id: "default_notification_channel_id",
        android_channel_id: "default_notification_channel_id", // For Android >= 8
        channel_name: "Default Notification Channel", // For Android >= 8
        click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"

      },
      data: {
        id: "notification",
        dataNotification: JSON.stringify(notification), 
        click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"

      },

    };
    var options = {
      priority: "high",
      click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
      timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24,
    };
    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token.token, payload, options)

      .then(function (response) {
        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
      });
  }
}
```